# how to get only the name of the image and not the whole path in Express js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to add only the name in the mysql table 
if I try to utilser req.files.name his works but the problem that the name of the image is encoded in the file

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({KeepExtensions: true, 
                            uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, '/picture')}));

exports.insertPhoto = function(req, res){
   db.addPhoto({name: req.body.name, photo: req.files.picture.path});
   res.redirect('/album');  
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try spliting by the `path.sep` and getting only the last part:

```
var filename = req.files.picture.path.split(path.sep).pop();
```

or even shorter:

```
var filename = path.basename(req.files.picture.path);
```

Comment: ReferenceError: path is not defined at exports.insertPhoto

Comment: Use `var path = require('path');` to use this module.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`path.basename(p, [ext])`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_p_ext):

```
path.basename(req.files.picture.path);
```

Comment: ReferenceError: path is not defined at exports.insertPhoto